# How can i set a system default ringtones as the default Ringtone of my app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to avoid to use MethodChannel , because i dont really know write native android code(kotlin/java).
I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_helper to access the system default ringtones but i want let user choose which one he wants and set it to default ringtone of my app.

how can i manage to do it in flutter? Are there any packages available? or the only way to do is using the MethodChannel?

thanks in advance